# Python argparse with Nagios check

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to fix a Op5 check but I can't seem to get the -H argument to be used as the hostname in the ssh connection. I'm not very good at python but learning as I go.

```
import paramiko
import argparse
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Argument parsing
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    epilog='Developed by %s - For more information see: "%s"'
    % (author, url))

parser.add_argument('-H', '--hostname', dest='hostname', required=True, help='Host name, IP Address')

args = parser.parse_args()

ssh.connect('hostname='args', username='', password='')
```

Probably missing stuff but I could use some help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take the quotes out of `hostname` - keyword argument labels don't need quotes, like you've done for `username` and `password`:

```
ssh.connect(hostname=args, username='', password='')
```

Then you need to access the correct argument from the `args` object - you can find what it's called from what you specified as `dest` when declaring your argument with `add_argument`:

```
ssh.connect(hostname=args.hostname, username='', password='')
```

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you for the good explanation for it as well :)